# How to get the CentOS 5.6 alsa drivers which will really work with one shot, without any internet

Tags: linux, centos, freebsd, fedora, video

I have one chance to install this in my server on site. Server that i am running is CentOS 5.6 (Dell R310, RAID1) where i need to install alsa-sound driver so that anything related to audio recording from rtsp is working (rail station/rail passing video recording including audio, where audio is not working).

Unfortunately i do not have any kind of internet in that odd none human location so yum will not work for me.

I need a offline way to install alsa drivers including missing dependencies if arise. What and where i can download this to my usb or cd? so that i can successfully install it (like mission complete).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have access to a machine which does have internet connectivity and access to a yum repository containing a driver package which you know works then you should be able to download it and all it's dependencies using `yumdownloader` and `repoquery`:

```
yumdownloader <package-name>
yumdownloader `repoquery --requires --resolve <package-name>`
```

should do the trick I think. Then on the disconnected machine you can install the whole lot:

```
yum localinstall *.rpm
```